# ２つのカラムで集計して２つ目のカラムを横に並べたい

Tags: google-spreadsheet

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| key | value |
| 1 | o |
| 2 | x |
| 1 | x |
| 1 | o |

というテーブルがあったときに

| key | o | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | o | 2 |
| 1 | x | 1 |
| 2 | o | 0 |
| 2 | x | 1 |

という感じの結果が得たいです

```
=QUERY(A3:B, "SELECT A, B, count(B) WHERE B IS NOT NULL GROUP BY A, B ORDER BY count(B) DESC")
```

のように単純に２列で集計してしまうと以下のようにすべて縦に並んでしまいます

```
        count 
1   o   2
1   x   1
2   x   1
```

１つ１つ countif 文でセル１個１個指定すればできるとは思うんですが
単独クエリで一気にやる方法はないでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

単純ではないですが、元のデータの下にarrayformulaで全パターンの配列を作成したものを結合させて、最後のqueryで空欄排除と countしたものを -1

```
=Query({A1:B;
ARRAYFORMULA((SPLIT(FLATTEN(unique(A2:A)&"_"&transpose(unique(B2:B))),"_",,FALSE)))},
"select Col1,Col2,count(Col2)-1 where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null 
group by Col1,Col2")
```